# How do I enable the inspect element in the Spotify App?

Tags: html, spotify

I don't know any way to open inspect element on my Spotify Application, there is no option anywhere and no keyboard shortcuts work.

I tried the second solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732367/debugging-spotify-apps-in-javascript-theres-gotta-be-a-better-way#:%7E:text=The%20Spotify%20application%20contains%20the,from%20your%20%7E%2FSpotify%20folder.) but it didn't do anything.
I also searched the web and tried Spicetify, but nothing works.

Comment: The inspect element feature is built into the browsers, not necessarily the app.  Are you talking about the web-app? or looking at the app where? in your computer's browser?

Comment: I'm talking about the application on my local computer. The question I mentioned did not work for me and I was wondering why. I hope this cleared some stuff up.

Comment: As I mentioned, that's a browser feature. It's not necessarily in the app

Comment: OP means the Electron app. Being essentially just Chromium they have dev-tools built in but it can be disabled by developers. That said it can usually be enabled again, e.g. Discord has a funny config option you can add to turn it on again. Don't know about Spotify unfortunately but it's probably hackable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with Spicetify; you need to set the `enable-devtools` parameter when you start it:

`spicetify enable-devtools`

and then right-click on a section of the app that does not override the right click. That will open up the context menu and you can navigate to "Inspect element".

Ref: https://spicetify.app/blog/your-first-extension/#first-step